# Trouble with Application Support directory

Tags: swift, cocoa

I searched for my problem with identifying location of the "Application support" on SO. However the various solutions I found are not working for me. Here's the code I'm using to locate a file I want to read/write from.

```
private var databaseUrl: URL?
{
    let file = "MyApp/MyFile.txt"

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
        return path
    }
    return nil
}
```

The Bundle Identifier of my app I have set to "MyApp" instead of "com.xxx.yyy.Myapp" which Xcode was using by default, and which I don't want. I was expecting to get a path like this...

```
/Users/griftopia/Library/Application Support/MyApp/MyFile.txt
```

This would be consistent with how I see other apps create files on my machine. However, what I am actually getting is this...

```
Users/griftopia/Library/Containers/MyApp-66665055012bb589084e4aeda209f212b5f695c7/Data/Library/Application Support/Myfile.txt)
```

Needless to say I want to say within the sandbox, but I thought Application Support is in the sandbox, but not expecting the path I got. Appreciate any insight

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your results are normal for a sandboxed macOS app. Sandboxed apps will be in ~Library/Containers/<app id> as opposed to ~/Library/Application Support/<app id>.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You just want confirmation that that's what a sandbox path looks like?

Comment: My question based on earlier comments is now two-fold. rmaddy - If the result I am getting is expected then why do I see other apps I install on my machine write to locations such as the one I'm expecting. @John Caswell - Now I'm confused whether the result I'm expecting is not sandbox compliant, and if so, then I need to know how to make an exception to allow my app to access /Users/griftopia/Library/Application Support/MyApp location and nothing else. I need to make it easier to locate the file, which once again is what I see other apps doing.